# $_SESSION not saving values between php zend controllers in XAMPP

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, xampp

Folks,

I trust all is well.

I am having an issue with my $_SESSION not passing values from one controller to another in my zend application. The issue is only happening on my local desktop environment. (Windows 8 XAMPP Version 5.6.8). When I run the code on my unix server it runs OK.
This is the code that I use to set the session variable in my first controller:

```
$_SESSION["child_code"] = $status["child_code"];
$_SESSION["bridgit_child_code"] = $status["bridgit_child_code"];
$_SESSION["sessionId"] = $status["session_id"];
$_SESSION["bridgit_rec_id"] = $status["bridgit_rec_school_code"];
$_SESSION["school_code"] = $status["reg_school_code"];
```

When run the following code in the first controller the session data appears properly:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

This is the code that I am using to get the session data in my second controller:

```
$this->aParameters["school_code"] = $_SESSION["school_code"];
$this->aParameters["child_code"] = $_SESSION["child_code"];
$this->aParameters["sessionId"] = $_SESSION["sessionId"];
```

However none of the data is there I verified it by printing out the session data here:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I have tried to set the session.auto_start to 1 in my php.ini but if I do my application crashes.

I believe that this is an issue with how my XAMPP is set up since the code works on my Unix server.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Andy

Comment: Do sessions work at all in your windows environment or just not with this specific code?  One thing to check is that `session.save_path` exists & is writable.

Comment: I checked and the session.save_path exists and is writable.

Answer (score 1):

According to Zend 1.12 [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.multiuser.sessions.html) sessions works something like this.

```
$mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
$mysession->child_code = $status["child_code"];
print_r($_SESSION);
```

At your next controller.

```
$mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Read the documentation if you are using [Zend 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.storage.html).